# Divisibility induction proof - question about fractions

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question about the example of divisibilty induction proof.
Here's the problem [the expression must be divisible by 8]:

$5^{n+1} + 2*3^n + 1 = 8*k$

I know that probably I have to proceed like this:

$5^{n+1}*5 + 2*3^n*3 +1 = 5 * (5^{n+1}+2*3^n+1)  - 2*2*3^n - 4 = 5 * (8k) - 4*3^n - 4$

And now my question is, if it's possible to write it as:

$5*(8k) - 8( \frac{1}{2} 3^n +  \frac{1}{2}) $

So I'd like to know whether I can create fractions solving such examples.

Thanks

Comment: You can create fractions, but you might be misled by them about divisibility. For instance $8\times(\frac123^n)$ is **not** divisible by $8$, for integer $n$.

Comment: I cannot follow what you did. In general, for induction proofs it is best to first clarify to yourself two things: what is the inductive hypothesis? What is your base case? I don't think the former is clear to you at the moment.

Comment: the inductive hypothesis is the first equation, and the base case I omitted, that's true. Replacing 'n' by '1' I get 32, so it works. Anyway, I really don't know how to do the example without these fractions, which, as I understand, are not legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prove it is as follows.

The result is true if $n=0$ in which case the number is equal to 8. Suppose the result holds for $n$. We prove the result holds for $n+1$, so we want to show that
$$5^{n+2}+2\cdot 3^{n+1}+1$$
is divisible by 8. To do this, we subtract the number for $n$ to get
$$5^{n+2}+2\cdot 3^{n+1}+1-( 5^{n+1}+2\cdot 3^{n}+1)$$
which is equal to
$$ 5^{n+1}(5-1)+2\cdot 3^{n}(3-1)$$
or in other words
$$4(5^{n+1}+3^n)$$
Since the two terms in parentheses are odd, the sum is even, so the whole difference is an even number times 4, which is a multiple of 8. The result follows by induction.

Comment: thank you! I would never come up with the idea of the even sum.

Comment: @Gerda you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've set things up here, the last bit is hidden, use it only if you cannot figure the stuff out. Even then, I did not finish the proof, but you will be on your way. Hope this helps. I strongly encourage you to think of induction this way, later on it will save you some headaches.

$$P(m):= \text{If an integer has the form } 5^{n+1} + 2*3^n + 1 \text{ for any } n\in\mathbb{N} \text{ then it is divisible by 8}$$

Proof by induction:

Suppose $P(m)$ for an arbitrary, but fixed integer smaller than $M,$ so $m<M.$ Note that $P(0)=8$ which is divisible by $8.$ We want to show $P(M)$ is true.

Suppose the hypothesis of $P(M)$ is true. That is, we have an integer of the form $5^{M+1} + 2*3^M + 1.$ Then we have,

$$5^{M+1} + 2*3^M + 1= \stackrel{\text{5 of these}}{\overline{5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}}}+  +3^M+3^M + 1$$

$$5^{M+1} + 2*3^M + 1= 5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}+\stackrel{\text{3 of these}}{\overline{3^{M-1}+3^{M-1}+3^{M-1}}}+3^M + 1$$

$$5^{M+1} + 2*3^M + 1= 5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}+2*3^{M-1}+3^{M-1}+3^M + 1$$
By the inductive hypothesis for $P(M-1),$

> $$5^{M+1} + 2*3^M + 1= 5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}+5^{M}+3^{M-1}+3^M +8k$$
> $$5^{M+1} + 2*3^M + 1= 4*5^{M}+3^{M-1}+3^M +8k$$
> $$5^{M+1} + 2*3^M + 1= 4*5^{M}+4*3^{M-1} +8k$$
> $$5^{M+1} + 2*3^M + 1= 4(5^{M}+3^{M-1}) +8k.$$

Comment: thank you very much! it's indeed extremely lucid written like that.

Answer (score 0):

When $n=0$ we have
$$5^{0+1}+2\cdot 3^{0}+1=8\equiv0\mod(8)$$
Let the statement be true for $n=k$ then for $n=k+1$ one has
$$5^{k+2}+2\cdot3^{k+1}+1=5\cdot5^{k+1}+6\cdot3^{k}+1=(5^{k+1}+2\cdot3^k+1)+4(5^{k+1}+3^{k})$$
but 
$$(5^{k+1}+2\cdot3^k+1)+4(5^{k+1}+3^{k})\equiv4(5^{k+1}+3^{k})\mod(8)$$
On the other hand 
$$5^{k+1}+3^{k}\equiv0\mod(2)$$
therefore 
$$4(5^{k+1}+3^{k})\equiv0\mod(8)$$

Comment: thank you. I couldn't hit on an idea of this equation divisible by 2. have a nice day!

Comment: @Gerda: You're welcome!